# Laravel 5.3 - I don't want the '/' route to redirect to login

Tags: laravel-5.3

I have 2 part in the laravel homepage.
One page is admin page and the other page is user page.
The admin page have to login, but user page don't have to login.

```
Route::get('/', 'NewsController@getIndex');

Auth::routes();

Routes::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    ...
});
```

How to solve this problem using the routes/web.php in laravel 5.3?
help me.

Comment: can you please share your codes in route.php file ?

Comment: sorry, i shared my code.

Comment: you can use Route group and prefix , like -  Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'App\Controllers'), function() {Route::get('/', 'adminController@login') } and same for users Route::group(array('prefix' => 'user', 'namespace' => 'App\Controllers'), function() {Route::get('/', 'NewsController@getIndex') }

Comment: it has no action, in addition it has errors, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code is followed

```
<?php

Auth::routes();
```

if permission is user->

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {

    Route::get('/', 'ViewnewsController@getIndex');
    ...
});
```

if permission is admin->

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

    Route::match(['get'], '/home', function () {
        ...
    });
    ...
});
```